# Prove that it's false that the connected components of $K \cup \{0\}$ are singletons.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This is a question with respect to standard topology:

**Prove it's false that: the connected components of $K \cup \{0\}$ are singletons.**

$$K := \left\{\dfrac{1}{n} \big\vert \, n \in N_{\geq 0}\right\}$$

I already proved that connected components of $K$ are singletons by saying $N$ is a discrete set, thus $K$ is a discrete set, so the only connected open set for $K$ is singletons.

And for this question, I followed the above method and wants to say: we can always find an open set that contains $0$, maybe $(-1,1)$? But not sure how to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $N_{\geq 0}$? And what topological space is $K$ a subspace of?

Comment: Probably it is $K=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=K\cup\{0\}$. Any subset $A$ of $X$ containing two distinct points is disconnected.

Indeed, if we have $1/m,1/n\in A$, with $m>n$ then the set $A$ is the disjoint union of
$$
\bigl[(-\infty,r)\cap A\bigr]\cup\bigl[(r,\infty)\cap A\bigr]
$$
where $r$ is an irrational number such that $1/m<r<1/n$. The two sets are open in $A$ and not empty.

Similarly if we have $0$ and $1/n$, just take an irrational $r$ with $0<r<1/n$.

Therefore the statement you're assigned with is wrong: *the connected components of $K\cup\{0\}$ are singletons* is the correct statement.

Comment: @Liz It’s the same argument for showing that the rationals are a totally disconnected space.